# Publishing apps to google play

Tags: android, google-play, publish

OK so in order to make a Google play account to distribute, I have to like make this Google wallet thing.. I want to know if it's allowed to do this if you are under 18. Also, for things like AdMob do you have to be over 18? Thanks!

Comment: read their documentation in respect to what you want to do okay..

Comment: It's not extremely clear.. I just don't want to try and do something and then find out that it wasn't allowed..

Answer (score 0):

I have also wondered about this, but the simple answer seems like no unless you were to have your parents to do some parts for you.

This was taken from the Terms of Service just for a Google Play account:

"**Age**

Only users 13 years of age or older are permitted to use Google Play, and users under 18 must have their parent or legal guardian's permission to use Google Play."
"
More information can be found from the [Google Play Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/about/android-developer-policies.html)

That is only to use Google Play. On the other hand to become a developer, in order to distribute your application (Most likely a android app), you would have to pay a initial 25 dollar fee, and go on with additional steps, as [shown here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468?hl=en)

In order to pay the initial fee, you would have to prove a valid credit card information which requires you to be the age of 18.

On the other hand, for AdMob you would have to read their own license and term of services just like you would for any third party application or service.

If you liked my answer, please mark this as the approved answer.
I will try to improve this answer as I gather more information.

Comment: Yes I know but can I just get a parent to pay that 25 dollars and then after all the payments are made to my bank account(you don't have to be 18 to have a bank account)?

Comment: Basically what I am asking is does the person paying the 25 dollars also have to be the person that is going to be distributing?

Comment: TheMAAAN am also under 18, am 15 and I had the same question as you. But everywhere it seems that you can get you're parents to do so but I am not sure and would advise sending a email to Google services asking them this questions specifically. I have also wondered if I were to do that, how would I get paid later on once I got my own credit card? Would the initial card used be permanent or not?

Comment: But how specifically? So you would be using your parent's bank account?

Comment: Am sorry, I just dont know. Am just going to wait until am 18 to make a account everything, i want to make sure to avoid legal soup

Answer (score 0):

you cant sign up for a adsense account(AdMob ) if you are under 18

[read this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/14230?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from admob's site

> If you are not yet 18, you may have a parent or guardian submit an application using their own Google Account. If their application is approved, all payments will be issued in this person’s name.

Google Wallet's ToS

> By agreeing to these Terms of Service, you represent the following:
>   You are between 13 and 17 years of age and creating a Google Wallet account for the sole and limited purpose of redeeming Google Play Gift Card value for select items that are eligible for purchase by you on Google Play, subject to applicable laws and upon Google's discretion;
>   or
>   You are 18 years old or older; and
>   Capable of entering into a legally binding agreement.

So for admob you can use a parent's or guardian's assistance (so they will earn the money on their account), while on Google Wallet it seems that you can't earn money under 18, you can probably get a parent/guardian's assistance as well.

Keep in mind you don't need Google Wallet for free apps, I've uploaded many free android games but I'm not allowed to own Google Wallet where I live. You only need it for paid apps (or in-app purchase), you don't even need it for ads (like admob).

Comment: How do I get parent's assistance?

Comment: So you're saying the money will go to their bank account? But I want the money to go to my bank account. Can't they just give permission..?

Comment: @TheMAAAN if you want to use Google Wallet, I believe, you can't earn the money yourself (until you become 18), but personally I don't think it's a big issue, just tell your parents/guardian to open a bank account for you on their name, in such a way that you can withdraw money by yourself with a card, so it will be like it's yours. I know that you want it to be in your name, I understand the feeling, but you have to be patient until you become 18 :)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! But how about for ads, not for Google Wallet?

Comment: @TheMAAAN as it states in my answer admob needs a parent/guardian to make an account as well, you can do the same as I described, you can also send money from admob to a paypal account (but i'm not sure about age limit there either), in the end you have to use a parent/guardian account to earn money

Comment: No they took out paypal.. so I have to get a parent's bank account. Ok then

Comment: @TheMAAAN oooh sorry I was using admob like 3-4 months ago I don't remember, my apologies :D

Comment: Ok is there any way for me to contact admob? I have looked everywhere trying to but they don't give an email or number. Or should I contact Google directly?

Comment: @TheMAAAN I don't think you need to contact them, if a parent/guardian makes an admob account in their name there is no need to contact them even if you are the one making activity in that account. Just keep in mind that the parent/guardian can get in trouble depending on your actions. (if for example you started using foul language using that account, your parent/guardian may be banned from admob or something similar)

Comment: No I want to call them for another reason. Do you know how I might go about doing this?

Comment: @TheMAAAN with a quit google search I found this : http://www.admob.com/home/contact I couldn't find any e-mail, i'm not sure how you can contact them, sorry